# Plotting rectangles in different subplots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot rectangles in different subplots (find the code below), but it doesn't work. With arrays of numbers the code works (and I get the three subplots), however, with Rectangles is different, and I get two empty subplots and one with the rectangle. Any ideas about what's wrong? Thanks!

```
n = 3
fig = plt.figure()

for i in xrange(n):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(n, 1, i+1)
    ax.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((i,0), 100, 100, color="green"))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake you are doing is adding `(i,0)` in the `matplotlib.Patches.Rectangle` section. When you do so:

For the first loop, `i` is 0 and the co-ordinates are `(0,0)`.

In the second loop your `i` becomes 1, so the co-ordinates will becomes `(1,0)`! This makes the lower left of your rectangle to take co-ordinates `(1,0)`.

This code will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

n = 3
fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(n):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(n,1,i+1)
    ax.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,0), 100, 100, color="green"))

plt.show()
```

The reason this works is that the co-ordinates of your lower left of the rectangle is always `(0,0)`. This produces [image]

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think that the increasing `x` coordinates were a mistake. But your solution still only show a *very* small part of the rectangles.

Comment: @hitzg yes that's true. The OP wanted three subplots with rectangles in it in the first place!! So the mistake the OP was making was rectified

Comment: @ThePredator +1 for "rectified" pun.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib does not automatically set the axes limits when drawing patches. The patches in your example are drawn, but the second and third have coordinates `(1,0)` and `(2,0)` and are out of the standard axes limits `(0,1)`.
You can let matplotlib do that for you with:

```
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
```

or do it manually:

```
ax.set_ylim((0,110))
ax.set_xlim((0,110))
```

In both cases you have to do in your loop (i.e. for each axes) and *after* your call to `add_patch`.